# NET8 + MAUI: ListView is not resized when the window resizes

Tags: c#, windows, maui

I'm creating an app with MAUI and NET8. I'm facing a funny issue with Windows. Consider the following screenshot

[image]

Basically, this is a `ListView`

```
<ListView x:Name="listDictionaries" 
            x:DataType="vm:DictionaryListViewModel"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Dictionaries}" 
            ItemSelected="listDictionaries_ItemSelected"
            SelectionMode="Single" HasUnevenRows="True" 
            CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" 
            HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill"
            IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}"
            RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="dt:Dictionary">
            <ViewCell>
                <!-- UI stuff -->
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

It is working. If I resize the window, it is not possible to scroll the `ListView` in any way. Also, I added in the *MauiProgram.cs* those lines:

```
.ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>
{
#if WINDOWS
        events.AddWindows(windows => windows
                .OnWindowCreated(window =>
                {
                    window.SizeChanged += OnSizeChanged;
                }));
#endif
})
```

and at the bottom of the file

```
#if WINDOWS
static void OnSizeChanged(object sender, 
    Microsoft.UI.Xaml.WindowSizeChangedEventArgs args)
{
    ILifecycleEventService service = MauiWinUIApplication.Current.Services.GetRequiredService<ILifecycleEventService>();
    service.InvokeEvents(nameof(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window.SizeChanged));
}
#endif
```

but it is not working. Here the live example

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: You don't have to use ```HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill"``` for listview.

Comment: Try using ```VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"```.

Answer (score 0):

Just share two workarounds here.

**Option 1**, use **VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"** instead of VerticalOptions="Fill"

```
<ListView x:Name="listDictionaries" 
       ...
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        ...
        >
```

**Option2**, use the Grid (instead of StackLayout) as the outer container,

```
<Grid ...>
    <ListView 
         HorizontalOptions="Fill" 
         VerticalOptions="Fill">
     ...
</Grid>
```

Both of the above methods can make the ListView scroll.

Hope it helps.